# Qt: How do I get the currently running window?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, user-interface, qt, qtestlib

I'm writing a test app which simulates key presses and I would like to get what window is displayed after each key presses. Here's the code block.

```
std::auto_ptr<MyForm> pForm(new MyForm(3,3)); 
QTest::keyPress(pForm.get(), Qt::Key_0);
```

After pressing 0 here, A window is gonna show up and I would like to check what window it is so I could QCompare/evaluate it later.

Any Ideas?

**Updated:**

I'm getting a segmentation fault when I use

```
std::auto_ptr<MyForm> pForm(new MyForm(3,3)); 
QTest::keyPress(pForm.get(), Qt::Key_0); 
QWidget *pWin = QApplication::activeWindow();
QCOMPARE(pWin->windowTitle(), QString("My Second Menu"));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If all your windows have been created through your application, you can use the [`QApplication`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#details) class.
By example, the [`activeWindow()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#activeWindow) function returns the widget that have the input focus. But there's a lot of other functions that can help you.

Hope that helps

Comment: I'm getting a segmentation fault though. I might be doing something wrong... I updated the code block above... :(

Comment: As explain in the documentation, the return pointer can be null if no window has the input focus. This can happened where widow has no keyboard input widget. Try to add a QTextEdit in your test windows.

Comment: The problem is, the window that appears after each key press is a Form with a Menu... I can't just add a qtextedit or just modify the application that I need to test... :( . Is there any other way to get the pointer of the currently active window?

Comment: Is it because there isn't really any activated window when you're just simulating?

Comment: An active window is a window that has the keyboard input focus. Try to set focus to the window or menu before calling activeWindow().

Comment: links are dead.